# Dynamic recipient in form

Tags: forms, typo3, fluid, extbase

I have a custom extension with list and detail of teachers. On the detail page I include a form with code:

```
<formvh:render persistenceIdentifier="1:/form_definitions/myform.yaml" />
```

I need to set the recipient with the teacher's email shown on the page. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by writing a [custom form finisher](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/9.5/Concepts/Finishers/Index.html#write-a-custom-finisher).

- Add a hidden field to your form which holds the the ID of the teacher
- Fetch that id in your form finisher and load the Teacher model by your repository

A (not complete) example of a form finisher, which loads recipient data from a custom model and sends the mail to this specific data:

```
class EmailToContactPersonFinisher extends EmailFinisher
{
/**
 * Executes this finisher
 * @see AbstractFinisher::execute()
 *
 * @throws FinisherException
 */
protected function executeInternal()
{
    /** @var FormRuntime $formRuntime */
    $formRuntime = $this->finisherContext->getFormRuntime();
    if ($formRuntime->getResponse()->getRequest()) {
        if ($formRuntime->getResponse()->getRequest()->hasArgument('contactPerson')) {
            $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
            /** @var ContactPersonRepository $repository */
            $contactPersonRepository = $objectManager->get(ContactPersonRepository::class);
            /** @var ContactPerson $contactPerson */
            $contactPerson = $contactPersonRepository->findByUid($formRuntime->getResponse()->getRequest()->getArgument('contactPerson'));
        }
    }
    // override contactPerson related options
    if ($contactPerson instanceof ContactPerson) {
        if ($contactPerson->getEmail()) {
            $recipientAddress = $contactPerson->getEmail();
        }
    }
    $this->setOption('recipientAddress', $recipientAddress);
    parent::executeInternal();
}
}
```

You can also have a look at the standard emailFinisher, which gives you quick idea on the architecture.
sysext/form/Classes/Domain/Finishers/EmailFinisher.php